# How to call ts function from js code and pass variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this situation where on clicking the html element i am fetching value of attribute in `home.ts` using jquery. When the button is clicked,I want to call a function and pass this fetched attribute's value in a variable in the called function.

Below is my code:

`**home.html**`

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <span action="10004">Quick Task</span>
</div>
```

`**home.ts**`

```
//declare var $: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import $ from "jquery"; //intentional use of jQuery

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  actionid;

  ngOnInit(){
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      console.log("Inside Event Listener");
      event.preventDefault();
        var link_id = $(event.target).attr("action");
        console.log("Actionid is:: " + link_id);
      //  this.actionid = link_id;
      //  var x = this.callpagedata();
  });
  }

  callpagedata(){
console.log("callpagedata function fired,actionid is::", this.actionid)
  }

}
```

### Edit

Something like this needs to be used:

`this.actionid = HTMLElement.addEventListener<"click">.......`

Comment: can you bind an event (i.e. `onclick`) to your HTML? - I think you should read about event binding in angular.  It will save you all the ugly code you have in your `ngOnInit(...)` function and deprecate the need to use jQuery (at least for this usecase) -> here's a succint tutorial on binding click event: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-bind-click-event-angular-2/

Comment: i know that well, but there is some need to fetch the value this way, i need to fetch the action id which is given dynamically and pass it to a function

Comment: I see... are you able to use good-ol' fashioned `<span action="10004" onclick=callpagedata(this)>Quick Task</span>` ?

Comment: give me the value of action attribute, if i can fetch that in a variable like `this.actionid` , then things will work

Comment: something like this has to be used `this.actionid = HTMLElement.addEventListener<"click">.......`

Comment: I am getting closer, if you can fit in my code - `this.actionid = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
this.actionid.addEventListener("click", () => { });`

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track. Like @ochi says, you should use data and event binding when you use Angular. You shouldn't use `getElementById()` and `addEventListener()` at all. Perhaps you can explain where the `action` value comes from? Why can't you use data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to HTML

```
<div id="mainDiv" #divRef>
  <span action="10004" #spanRef (click)="callAMethod($event)">Quick Task</span>
</div>
```

Then

get Reference from TS file (component):

```
@Comp..
...
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('divRef') divReference: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('spanRef') spanReference: ElementRef;
  public action=null;

  callAMethod(){
     this.action = this.spanReference.attr('action')
  }
}
```